# Datamaps - eliminating white space at top/bottom

Tags: javascript, mapping, datamaps

Several datamaps templates have a *lot* of whitespace above and below the actual outline of the continents (for example, the "basic" and US maps have this; chloropleth does not have much whitespace. See: http://datamaps.github.io/)

Is there a way to shrink that empty space?

I don't see any such option in the documentation, but would it be possible to go into the map source code itself and simply edit out this whitespace? Any tips on how that might be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fix I used for this issue was to fiddle with the CSS properties of the div that holds the map. This also allows you to better position the elements based on what you have around it.